# haproxy regex escaping equal to sign in URL with parameters

Tags: regex, pcre, haproxy

I need help with haproxy regular expression for URL with parameters

here is use case

/my/service/api/v6/myOffers/myItemSearch?itemId=12345&itemType=UPS

to

/new/v1/contextPath/offers/UPS/12345

Here is what i have tried, which is not working, so i need your help...

```
reqirep ^([^\ ]*)\ /my/service/api/v6/myOffers/myItemSearch?itemId=(.*)&itemType=(.*)$ \1\ /new/v1/contextPath/offers/\3/\2
```

I think having multiple equal to sign in the URL need to be handled in a a different way, not sure how..can you please suggest

Comment: What version of HAProxy?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot 169

Comment: Parameters could be in any order, so I think it might be cleaner, instead of a regex, to use the [`url_param`](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#7.3.6-url_param) layer 7 fetch, available in 1.6+, with something resembling `http-request set-path /new/v1/contextPath/offers/%[url_param(itemType)] ...` but I have not yet had an opportunity to test a full solution that takes this approach.

Answer (score 0):

This finally worked for me:

```
reqirep ^([^\ ]*)\ /my/service/api/v6/myOffers/myItemSearch\?itemId\=(.*)(.&)itemType\=([^\s]+)(.*)$ \1\ /new/v1/contextPath/offers/\4/\2\5
```